# Multiple records in a table matched with a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, procedures

The architecture of my DB involves records in a Tags table. Each record in the `Tags` table has a string which is a `Name` and a foreign kery to the `PrimaryID's` of records in another `Worker` table.

Records in the Worker table have tags. Every time we create a Tag for a worker, we add a new row in the Tags table with the inputted Name and foreign key to the worker's PrimaryID. Therefore, we can have multiple Tags with different names per same worker.

**Worker Table**

```
ID         |   Worker Name    |    Other Information
__________________________________________________________________
1          |   Worker1        | ..........................
2          |   Worker2        | ..........................
3          |   Worker3        | ..........................
4          |   Worker4        | ..........................
```

**Tags Table**

```
ID         |Foreign Key(WorkerID) |    Name
__________________________________________________________________
1          |   1                  | foo
2          |   1                  | bar
3          |   2                  | foo
5          |   3                  | foo
6          |   3                  | bar
7          |   3                  | baz
8          |   1                  | qux
```

My goal is to filter `WorkerID`'s based on an inputted table of strings. I want to get the set of `WorkerID`'s that have the same tags as the inputted ones.  For example, if the inputted strings are `foo` and `bar`, I would like to return `WorkerID`'s 1 and 3. Any idea how to do this? I was thinking something to do with GROUP BY or JOINING tables. I am new to SQL and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of relational division. Here's one attempt:

```
select workerid 
from tags
where name in ('foo', 'bar')
group by workerid
having count(distinct name) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
select WorkerID
from tags where name in ('foo', 'bar')
group by WorkerID
having count(*) = 2
```

and this will retrieve your desired result/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) is an excellent resource on the subject.

While the answer from @Lennart works fine in Query Analyzer, you're not going to be able to duplicate that in a stored procedure or from a consuming application without opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks. To extend the solution, you'll want to look into passing your list of tags as a table-valued parameter since SQL doesn't support arrays.

Essentially, you create a custom type in the database that mimics a table with only one column:

```
CREATE TYPE list_of_tags AS TABLE (t varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

Then you populate an instance of that type in memory:

```
DECLARE @mylist list_of_tags
INSERT @mylist (t) VALUES('foo'),('bar')
```

Then you can select against that as a join using the GROUP BY/HAVING described in the previous answers:

```
select workerid 
from tags inner join @mylist on tag = t    
group by workerid
having count(distinct name) = 2
```

*Note: I'm not at a computer where I can test the query. If someone sees a flaw in my query, please let me know and I'll happily correct it and thank them.

Comment: Thank you! I am actually using a table type `StringList` with just one column which are strings. My purposes are for a stored procedure, so this is exactly what I was looking for. cheers!